# Web scraping webpage that requires login using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, authentication

Problem statement:

I have this webpage where each candidate in a list has link that contains some information that i want to scrape.

So for all candidates I have to click on the link and fetch details manually which is a tedious task.

I want to automate this please help me.

#### Candidate List

[image]

#### My solution:

I think that to automate this task i should write a script that would click on each link and scrape the data.

But I want to know how can i scrape a webpage that requires login.

The web page which you see can be accessed only by login page.

If apart from this method anyone has a better solution to do this task - please help.

Thanks:)

Comment: How many items do you want to scrape and how frequently do you want to do it? What programming langs do you know?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you share some code illustrating your problem? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Comment: @21st i want tos crape like 500 items but only once as of now.
I know java,javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to scrape the data once and store it, you can use [webscraper.io](https://www.webscraper.io/) chrome extension and save the data in the desired file format. Here the scraping will be done right in your browser so, you can manually log in once and start scraping.

Else if you want to integrate the scraping process in the server and serve the data to your users, you can use libraries like axios/request to make HTTP requests and use cheerio to extract required data from HTML.

You can also use headless chrome node API, Puppeteer.

Comment: Thank you @mounish the extension worked as per my need.You really made my work easier.
But also i want to learn web scraping and would like to code the solution myself.If you could suggest any module in node.js and share some code snippet regarding the login issue that would definitely be helpful.
Thanks again :)